# "The population is 57,000" or "the population is 57,000 people"?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, american-english

I'm having a devil of time googling this, so my apologies if this question has been answered before. Internet searching has been all but worthless, what with boolean cues being imprecise as they are.

Which of the following sentences would be the usual choice?

> The population of Greenland is 57,000.

-or-

> The population of Greenland is 57,000 people.

The first sentence seems incomplete to me somehow, like it ends abruptly. I think it's just one of those indescribable feelings of wrongness.

The sentence would be used in an informational piece for children 10-11. I wonder if the addition of "people" would clarify what the sentence means to a younger audience. I also wonder if the audience might also find it abrupt if the sentence is used verbatim.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally no word is appended, though you may, depending on the audience, append "people", "persons", "souls", "inhabitants", et al.  However, saying "the population ... is" implies "people", and an additional word is really only needed if you say, eg, "Greenland is the home of 57,000 people".

Comment: What the determinative applies to should be clear from the context. *Population* usually refers to people, but if you're writing an article about musk oxen in Greenland, perhaps it would be safe to specify which mammal you're talking about.

Comment: The [first thing I saw in a Google search for "population meaning"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=population+meaning) was the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/population) definition and example **population** 
...
NOUN

1 All the inhabitants of a particular place:
_the island has a population of about 78,000_)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that's fair. I phrased my question incorrectly. What I meant was, "Which is better?" My apologies.

Comment: "Which is better?" sounds like it should be tagged *word choice*, except that tag requires a list of words, not whether or not to use a single one. Both of your examples are *grammatical*, so that tag doesn't fit. Unless that was your question, then the answer is a simple yes.

Comment: Remember that *population* comes from the Latin word for *people,* and you may start to find, as I do, that adding "people" to the end of the sentence is hopelessly, clumsily redundant, like saying "the dessert has a sugar content of 50 grams of sugar."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edwin Ashworth's answer very nicely addresses that "the variant without 'people' is much more common."

However it doesn't address "Why?". The reason is both simple and complex.

Simple: Population very literally means people.
[Origin: late 16th century (denoting an inhabited place): from late Latin populatio(n-), from the verb populare, from populus ‘people.’](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Apopulation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Complex: The word was also adopted by the sciences of biology and astronomy to discuss groupings within their fields.

Practical result:
People fluent in English realize that "population of people" is redundant (just like saying "human mankind" or "people populace"), and are therefore less likely to use it. However it is not *wrong*. 
So people specializing in other fields, or communicating to a mixed language audience might insert the word "people" for clarity, and people who don't know that its redundant might go either way.

So that is the actual answer to which is better... Knowing why to use a word vitalizes anything you have to say. If adding the word "people" does not clarify the meaning of the sentence, then avoid he redundancy. But if a situation benefits from having the most specific context possible, then the redundancy actually improves the sentence.

ps.
Once you start looking at "population of people" as redundant it may become very hard to use it at all, even when it's helpful. You may then find "human population" to be preferable. It's still redundant, but at least it doesn't having the rhyming syllables of "population people" which seem to knowingly mock the writer.

Answer (score 3):

[These two Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=population+of+ten+million%2Cpopulation+of+ten+million+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpopulation%20of%20ten%20million%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpopulation%20of%20ten%20million%20people%3B%2Cc0) (note that the "population of ten million" graph should have the "population of ten million people" 'subtracted', giving "population of ten million" - "population of ten million people", for a truer comparison with the "population of ten million people" graph) show that the variant without 'people' is much more common.

You can try this with other sensible pairs, and with Google searches.

Answer (score 1):

[I added asterisks to Edwin's query above](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=population+of+*+%2Cpopulation+of+*+people&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cpopulation%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20England%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20New%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cpopulation%20of%20*%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20young%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%2010%2C000%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20100%2C000%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20white%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20older%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%2050%2C000%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20old%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%2030%2C000%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20working%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%2020%2C000%20people%3B%2Cc0)  and it gives a rather edifying result in what the query expands into. Adding people is the done thing only when we are interested in a specific class of people. For instance, `The population of old people`. Otherwise `The population of 100000` is much more common.